# Bat file added to registry not working on windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, batch-file

I'm trying to make a bat file run at boot by adding it to the system registry; the bat is very easy, it's just:

```
mkdir new
```

Obviously when I normally run it, it works and a folder named "new" spawns in the bat file directory(Desktop), but when I try to add the file to both "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" and
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", add a string like "C:\[...]\Desktop\test.bat", on boot I see for a moment a cmd windows pop up and then immediately close but no "new" folder. Does anyone know how to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A start-up key such as:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"Run"="C:\users\bob\desktop\run.bat"
```

...where "run.bat" contains:

```
mkdir new
```

..will start in the following directory: "C:\windows\system32\".

The command line will be:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Users\bob\Desktop\run.bat" "
```

and it will be running as the user "bob".

Trying to create a directory in "C:\WINDOWS\system32\" will get you access denied.

If you like, you can put the command:

```
pause
```

in the batch file "before" and "after" your command(s) so you can see it happen at logon.  You can even run Process Monitor (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) after the first pause to see the outcome.

Comment: Any particular reason for the double quotes around the parameter, and the space between the last two quotes?