# PS2 Keyboard Functionality on Windows 10

Tags: keyboard

I've been experiencing my ps2 keyboard not functioning after "any" Windows 10 update. Fortunately, I have able to get it to work, after Googling this issue on the Web. I did reinstall the PS2 Standard keyboard driver, and change the i8042 port start value to 1 ( it was 3, after updating ). Thing is, I had to do this after every update. My question is, what ( if any ) procedure or settings can I use to keep from having to do this after every update? I always thought, if you change a registry entry, it stays the same. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I guess I should mention, my pc is a HP Pavilion Special Edition a6745f. Originally came preloaded with Windows Vista, which I have successfully upgraded to Windows 7 Home 64, now Windows 10 Home 64.

Answer (score 0):

Create .reg file (https://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntregquery.php) or skip to next step

Create .bat/powershell file which applies .reg file (or set registry directly from bat/powershell) when needed (https://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntregquery.php)

Add that .bat/powershell file to autostart or Run ([Bat file added to registry not working on windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1175295/bat-file-added-to-registry-not-working-on-windows))

(Disclaimer: links are random google links, no check was made if they are correct for Windows 10)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Seems a little "involved" for me, but, I have seemed to have solved the issue. USB to PS2 converter (active). I admit, I was quite skeptical, going with this solution, but, it works!! So, I guess that solves my issue.

Comment: Also refer [this](https://superuser.com/a/1090314/369805).